# DropDown Menu is hiding behind the section

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, bootstrap-4

I have a `dropdown menu` in the header but it is hiding behind the `section`. [image]

`Logout` button is in the top right below name which is hiding.
I have tried to add the below on the parent div but doesn't works:

```
overflow: visible !important;
position: relative;
z-index: 100;
display: block;
```

Below is my html code:

```
<div class="col-md-6 col-fix dropdown">
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    <% if current_user.center_profile.logo.url.present? %>
      <%= image_tag current_user.center_profile.logo.url, alt: "Center Logo", class: "centre", width: "35", height: "35" %>
    <% else %>
      <%= image_tag 'ic-centerlogo.png', alt: "Center Logo", class: "centre", width: "35", height: "35" %>
    <% end %>  
    <div class="profile-name" title="<%= current_user.center_profile.name %>">
      <%= current_user.center_profile.name %>
    </div>
    <%= image_tag "ic-dropdown.png", alt: "Logout", class: "centre profile-pic", width: "10", height: "5" %>
  </a>
  <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
    <%= link_to('Logout', destroy_user_session_path, method: 'delete', class: "dropdown-item", :data => {:confirm => 'Are you sure you want to logout?'}) %>
  </div>
</div>
```

Below is my css:

```
.dropdown {
overflow: visible !important;
position: relative;
z-index: 100;
display: block;
@include desktop {
    text-align: right;
}
@include tab {
    text-align: right;
}
@include mobile {
    margin-top: 15px;
}
div {
    &.dropdown-menu {
        box-shadow: 0 0 6px 0 rgba(169, 169, 169, 0.25);
        border: 0 none;
        position:relative;
        background-color:#ffffff;
        height:40px !important;
        width:116px !important;
        margin-top: 10px;
        z-index: 30;
        overflow: auto;
        padding: 0;
        &:after {
            content:'';
            position: relative;
            width: 10px;
            height: 10px;
            transform: rotate(45deg); /* Prefixes... */
            top: -5px;
            right: 10px;
            box-shadow: -1px -1px 10px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
            z-index: -1;
        }
        .dropdown-item {
            padding: .8rem 0;
            background: #ffffff;
            display: block;
            border-radius: 8px;
        }
    }
}


I also want to remove the `up triangle` from the section which is just below the drop down icon in the top right in the screenshot.
```

Comment: have you tried setting the z-index to a higher value just to rule out the possibility of stacking issues? i.e. set the z index value of dropdown to 9999. Also I notice that your dropdown-menu has a lower z index value than its parent which has 100.

Comment: I added z index as 10000 but no luck

Comment: how about getting rid of z-index from the dropdown-menu? It's kind of hard to figure out the layout of your website just from looking at the screenshot you provided but is there two popups going on (the login button and some filter bar thing)?

Comment: removed but not luck, the section one is fixed, page have only 1 drop down

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the below changes to make it works:

I removed the below from `dropdown` class

```
overflow: visible !important;
position: relative;
z-index: 100;
display: block;
```

The problem was in the `filter` div. It was having `z-index: 99999` . I changed it to 0 i.e. `z-index: 0` and it works.